# ¿Como recorrer resultado foreach perl telnet?

Tags: oracle, perl, telnet

Estoy haciendo una conexión desde perl a telnet realizo la conexión sin problemas, la idea es poder ejecutar un comando `traver l 0123456789 133 ainres icsx cont nt` y poder capturar esa respuesta para luego almacenarla en una base de datos

El resultado obtenido al ejecutar `traver l 0123456789 133 ainres icsx cont nt`  desde consola es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código perl**

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Telnet();
use warnings;

$central='DMS_VINA';
$ip_central='111.123.1.251';
$user='juan';
$password='soporte';

consulta_central($central,$ip_central,$user,$password);

sub consulta_central
{
    my $central =shift;
    my $ip_central=shift;

    print "-------------------------------\n";
    print "Inicia proceso central $central\n";

    my $telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>30, Errmode=>sub {&error($central) unless $_[0] =~ /eof/}, Prompt => '/>/' );

    $telnet->open($ip_central);
    $telnet->print($user, $password);
    $telnet->waitfor('/>/');

    my $comando = 'traver l 0123456789 133 ainres icsx cont nt';

    my @lines = $telnet->cmd( String => $comando, Timeout=>30, Prompt => '/>/' );

    foreach my $texto(@lines)
    { 
        print $texto;
    }
}
```

Respuesta al ejecutar el perl:

```
    Inicia proceso central DMS_VINA
     **
**                                                  **
** Example: ^Bhx
```

En donde los resultados no son los esperados.

**Que se espera:**

```
DIGIT TRANSLATION ROUTES

1 VIN21T7BVINA032       133                          ST

TREATMENT ROUTES.  TREATMENT IS: GNCT
1 BST3
2 LKOUT

+++ TRAVER: SUCCESSFUL CALL TRACE +++
```

Poder recorrer esos resultados para almacenarlos.

Comment: El prompt `/>/` es correcto? Prueba con el prompt por defecto. Utiliza `$telnet->cmd( String => $comando, Timeout=>30);` y mira a ver si así funciona